# Get list of students whose first name is before their last name alphabetically

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

So I have a list of students that have FirstName and LastName. How do I filter them with a LINQ query in the given way: their first name comes before last name alphabetically?

I tried something along the lines of

```
var newStudents =
        from s in students
        where s.FirstName < s.LastName
        select s;
```

The problem I'm facing here is that strings can't be compared that way.

The students also have a List of int containing their grades, with another query. I need to extract all students who have the grade 2 appear twice.
For example, I need to select a student with grades `{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 2 }` but ignore a student with grades `{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }`.

Comment: I suggest looking into LINQ's [`.OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`.ThenBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534743(v=vs.100).aspx) Also, here's an MSDN article on [how to sort data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx)

Comment: Could you be so kind and provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Also, your question is almost two separate questions.  I suggest removing the second question (about the grades) and asking it separately if needed.  It really doesn't have anything to do with sorting by name then by another name.

Comment: For the string issue you can use String.CompareTo() which is useful for sorting strings. [msdn on CompareTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx) If you could include more code revolving around how you're storing their grades, that'd be helpful.

Comment: If you solved your problem, post that _as an answer_.  Do not edit your question.

Comment: Thanks, `.CompareTo()` did the job. About the grades, I have a Class called Student and it has a Property  Marks of type `List<int>` that holds the marks of the given student. I am creating a new List of Students `List<Student>` and I have 10 students in that list, I need to take the students that have the mark 2 appear twice and store them in a separate list: `var poorStudents = students.Where(s => s.Marks.Contains(2));` Something like this, but it needs to check if the list contains the number 2, two times

Comment: @Darkbound ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

> Get list of students whose first name is before their last name alphabetically

This will filter out students whose `FirstName` is before `LastName` and orders by `FirstName`, then by `LastName`:

```
var newStudents = students
    .Where(s => String.Compare(s.FirstName, s.LastName, StringComparison.Ordinal) < 0) // Filter students whose FirstName is before LastName
    .OrderBy(s => s.FirstName) // Order by FirstName
    .ThenBy(s => s.LastName); // If FirstNames are equal, then order by LastName
```

Note that I'm using `StringComparison.Ordinal` which is case sensitive. You may want to use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Darkbound's solution:

```
var newStudents =
        from s in students
        where s.FirstName.CompareTo(s.LastName) < 0
        select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Linq to Objects this would work.

```
var filteredStudents = 
            from student in students
            where String.Compare(s.FirstName, s.LastName, StringComparison.Ordinal) < 0
            order by student.FirstName, student.LastName
            select student;
```

I don't know if it works in Linq to SQL too.

Answer (score 0):

Originally there were two questions (i rolled back the question):

1)

> How do I filter them with a LINQ query in the given way: their first
>   name comes before last name alphabetically?

2)

> I need to select a student with grades `{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 2 }` but ignore a
>   student with grades `{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }`.

As to the question no. 1: As other members, i do recommend to use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods.
As to the question no. 2: You have to group data and get count of grade 2 which appears twice. See an example (using LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    List<Student> stu = new List<Student>(){
        new Student("A", "B", new List<int>{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 2 }),
        new Student("B", "A", new List<int>{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }),
        new Student("B", "A", new List<int>{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 4 })
        };

    var qry = stu
        .OrderBy(s=>s.FirstName)
        .ThenBy(s=>s.LastName)
        .Where(s=>s.Grades.GroupBy(r=>r).Any(g=>g.Count(a=>a==2)>1));
    //qry.Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Student
{
    public Student(string sFName, string sLName, List<int> grades)
    {
        FirstName = sFName;
        LastName = sLName;
        Grades = grades;
    }

    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public List<int> Grades{get;set;}
}
```

Result:

```
FirstName LastName  Grades
A         B         2 
                    3 
                    4 
                    5 
                    2
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution to my second problem really works!
Could you please explain this line of code `.Where(s=>s.Grades.GroupBy(r=>r).Any(g=>g.Count(a=>a==2)>1));`

Comment: Well... `Where` accept boolean values. So, firstly i group data by grades, then i use `Any` method to return boolean for each record which fullfil the criteria (2 grade is occurs twice). That's all.